# jQuery itunes image slider

Tags: jquery

I'm working on my final project for my Web Design 2 course and I wanted to dress up my site a bit with jQuery.  Have you ever noticed in itunes or on the iOS that when you view your music  by albums, it shows the the covers in a image slider that looks really nice.  I want to do something similar to this minus the flip the covers do.  Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.secondImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
$('.thirdImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
$('.fourthImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
$(".item").hide(0).delay(2000).fadeIn(800);   // hides the columns div to ensure images are loaded
$("#loading").hide(0).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);   // hides the loading icon

$("#firstColumn").hover(function(){     
    $('.secondImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.thirdImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.fourthImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.firstImage').stop().animate({ width: '315px', height: "315px" }, 500);
});

$("#secondColumn").hover(function(){ 
    $('.firstImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.thirdImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.fourthImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.secondImage').stop().animate({ width: '315px', height: "315px" }, 500);
});

$("#thirdColumn").hover(function(){   
    $('.firstImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.secondImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.fourthImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.thirdImage').stop().animate({ width: '315px', height: "315px" }, 500);
});

$("#fourthColumn").hover(function(){  // when second div is hovered, set opacity of others to 0.5
    $('.firstImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.secondImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.thirdImage').animate({ width: '155px', height: '155px' }, 0);
    $('.fourthImage').stop().animate({ width: '315px', height: "315px" }, 500);
});
});
```

When the page loads, the main content area is hidden while a fake loading screen appears.  This was done simply because I thought it looks cool :).  The images re-size and become bigger like I want them to.  The problem is, if you go too fast then all the images re-size at the same time.  I thought that the .stop() function was supposed to cancel that but maybe I am doing something incorrectly.  Is there an easier way to do the .animate()?  I am open to any and all suggestions.  Tutorials or links to examples are appreciated as well.

Thank you all in advance!
- Mike

Comment: On the #fourthColulmn function, ignore comment there.  It was from an older function that I replaced.

Comment: Here is a link to a YouTube video showing the interface: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afy5BEdRz8A&feature=related).  If you notice the albums "flip" when you slide.  That is the only thing I **do not** want.  I will try and set up a demo on one of those sites.

Comment: I just posted my folder on one of my test sites.  I couldn't get the images to show on jsfiddle.  Here is the link: [link](http://www.fmatech.net/Web-Design/).  you can view the source code, there is nothing incriminating

Comment: Great. Now i see your issue. I'll help you with this one. sec.

Comment: Thanks. I think that what I was seeing wasn't really a problem.  I haven't spaced the images correctly yet so when all the images are bigger they overflow.

Comment: On a side note, the tiles will all be centered vertically as well.

Comment: You may want to cache those jquery selectors... :) Also, yes, .stop( true,true ) would help the jumpy behavior when hovering quickly.

Comment: Thank you, but when I add true, true and go semi fast it just keeps all of the images big.  In the event a user goes fast I would like them to remain smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example, take a look:

#### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ihuxas/8/edit)*

```
var imgWmarg = 159; // image with margins (px)
var imgW = 155;
var increaseWidth = 80; // px (both sides)

$('.item img').each(function(i,e){
  
  $(this).css({position:'absolute', left: '+='+(imgWmarg*i) });
  
  $(this).hover(function(){    
        $(this).css({zIndex:1}).stop(1).animate({ top:-(increaseWidth/2), left:((imgWmarg*i)-(increaseWidth/2)), width:(imgW+increaseWidth) },300);    
  }, function(){    
        $(this).stop(1).animate({ top:0, left:(imgWmarg*i), width:imgW }, 100, function(){
                $(this).css({zIndex:0});     // at the end of animation
        });
  });
  
});
```

What have I done:

- As the images are set position:relative, we have to set them with jQuery to absolute and dynamically reset their 'normal' positions by knowing the width with margins and their respective index N inside the parent element
- The `i` in `.each(function(i,e){` returns the index of each element to animate
- Multiplying that `i` (0,1,2,3) by the imgWmarg we have their positions.
- Than we undo - redo that positions on hover.

Comment: Oh my god this looks amazing!  I did notice when it is first rendered all of the images are stacked but that is an easy fix.  Thank you very much, without your help I would never been able to do this!

Comment: Thanks again for helping, I keep playing with it going back and forth lol

Comment: @MichaelGarrison I like it more with smaller resize, and shadows too (CSS3) : http://jsbin.com/ihuxas/5/edit

Comment: It looks really nice, how can I have it display everything inline to start instead of stacked up on the left? I was playing with it and couldn't figure it out

Comment: I really don't know how you mean: 'inline'. They are already inline!

Comment: Ah, chrome is stupid and needs in the CSS `left:0;` for the images! Here you go!: http://jsbin.com/ihuxas/8/edit

Comment: On my end it shows all the images stacked on top of each other and when you hover over the first, all of the images spread out to their correct locations

Comment: I pasted a new demo . take a look. Now works for me. You may try to change left:0; to left:0px;

Comment: That fixed it, I couldn't figure out what the issue was

Comment: Chrome needs some things to be defined, before beeing accessed by scripts. And we need that 0px from the images.

Comment: I think that the jQuery file I was using was outdated as well.  As soon as I linked the one from google api's it worked for me

Comment: It makes sense because it gives the script a starting value of 0 to build on

Comment: @MichaelGarrison Right. That's the exact reason that logically pointed me to the real issue.